# I am trying to get current word from textarea,where my cursor is clicked now

Tags: jquery

Here I get the word by selected using the following code,like by clicking i need to get

```
$('#select').click(function (e) {

    textAreaValue = $("#para")[0],
    startValue = textAreaValue.selectionStart,
    endValue = textAreaValue.selectionEnd,
    oldText = textAreaValue.value;
    text = oldText.substring(startValue, endValue);
    alert(text);
}
```

// I use this code to get current word  where my cursor is placed

$('#textarea').click(function() {

```
    textAreaValue = $("#para")[0];
        startValue = textAreaValue.selectionStart;
    endValue = textAreaValue.selectionEnd;
    oldText = textAreaValue.value;
    startPosition = startValue;
    textlength = (textAreaValue.value).length;
    while(startPosition >= 0 ){
     if(oldText.substring(startPosition-1, startPosition) == ' '){
         break;
     }
     startPosition--;
    }
    endPosition = endValue;
    while(true){
        var eval = oldText.substring(endPosition, endPosition+1);
         if(eval == ' ' || eval == '\n' || eval == '\r' || eval == '\t'|| endPosition == textlength){
             break;
         }
         endPosition++;
        }

    text =  oldText.substring(startPosition, endPosition);
    textAreaValue.selectionStart = startPosition;
    textAreaValue.selectionEnd = endPosition;
    alert(text);
    return false;

});
```

Answer (score 5):

If the user highlights text, you can get the selected text:

```
$('textarea').on('click', function() {
    var text = $(this).html();
    var start = $(this)[0].selectionStart;
    var end = $(this)[0].selectionEnd;
    var text = text.substr(start, end - start);
    alert(text);
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ud5R8/16/)

If the user just clicks in the textarea, you can get the word the cursor is on:

```
var stopCharacters = [' ', '\n', '\r', '\t']
$('textarea').on('click', function() {
    var text = $(this).html();
    var start = $(this)[0].selectionStart;
    var end = $(this)[0].selectionEnd;
    while (start > 0) {
        if (stopCharacters.indexOf(text[start]) == -1) {
            --start;
        } else {
            break;
        }                        
    };
    ++start;
    while (end < text.length) {
        if (stopCharacters.indexOf(text[end]) == -1) {
            ++end;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    var currentWord = text.substr(start, end - start);
    alert(currentWord);
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ud5R8/14/)

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery [textRange](https://github.com/dwieeb/jquery-textrange) plugin does this and more.

Comment: Thanks Krister Andersson

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily with browser's selection API:

```js
const selection = window.getSelection();

// Move cursor to the end of the word
selection?.modify('move', 'forward', 'word');

// Extend selection to the start of the word
selection?.modify('extend', 'backward', 'word');

// Get the selected text
const text = selection.toString();

// You can collapse selection later if you like
selection.collapse();
```