# Make every word inside an html Textarea selectable

Tags: javascript, html, angular, textarea

Need to make every word inside the textarea clickable.

```
<textarea [class.background]="setEnable" [disabled]="!setEnable" id="analyzerContent" placeholder="{{contentPlaceholder}}" [(ngModel)]="analyzerContent" >
```

Here the variable analyzerContent has the data to be filled inside the textarea.
Need to make every word inside this data clickable and the clicked word should be passed to a function.Any suggestions ?

Comment: What does "make every word inside this data clickable" mean exactly? What does currently prevent you clicking an word? ;-)

Comment: The possible solution could be using a div container with contenteditable attribute applied. This way you'll be able to easily manipulate the DOM inside the div container and wrap any word with a clickable element.

Comment: Sorry, my answer didn't make sense. I somehow assumed contenteditable.

Comment: Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20042356/i-am-trying-to-get-current-word-from-textarea-where-my-cursor-is-clicked-now

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer the link did provide some help. Any provision to underline the selected part of text area.?

Comment: There is nothing Angular specific. Just try to find some JS solution. If you run into issues making it work with Angular update the question or create a new one. I can't imagine there is no JS answer available if it is possible at all.